# Run LDAP queries on AD through JAVA Code

Tags: java, ldap, connection

I have configured ADDC on windows server 2012 R2 and I have added two users into DC - one is windows 8 and another one is ubuntu.

- Windows server 2012 username - `DC`
- Windows 8.1 username - `Win`
- Ubuntu username - `Linux`

I am trying to achieve this - I want to write java program in ubuntu, that will connect to ADDC and sends back, detailed user information on windows 8.1

My program is like -

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class LdapSearch {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

String sp = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, sp);

String ldapUrl = "ldap://server.com, dc=com";
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);

DirContext dctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

String base = "ou=name";

SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
String[] attributeFilter = { "cn", "mail" };
sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

String filter = "(&(sn=W*)(l=Criteria*))";

NamingEnumeration results = dctx.search(base, filter, sc);
while (results.hasMore()) {
  SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
  Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

  Attribute attr = attrs.get("cn");
  System.out.print(attr.get() + ": ");
  attr = attrs.get("mail");
  System.out.println(attr.get());
}
dctx.close();
}
```

I am referring to above program and trying to achieve connection to AD through LDAP java. I dont know how to get `ou`, `cn`, etc.. I am very much new to the concepts of LDAP, ADDC.

Any idea on this? Please let me know.

Thanks,
saurabh

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar scenario in C# so am not sure about the connection settings in Java but as for similarities you should  create a directory entry for the LDAP and provide the path, user name and password of authorized user who can access the active directory, i didnt provide DC in the path just the LDAP path and then the query filter parameters that searched based upon user first name was

```
Filter = "(& (SAMAccountName=" + name + ") (| (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(homeMDB=*))(!(msExchHomeServerName=*)))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(homeMDB=*)(msExchHomeServerName=*))) ))";
```

then it would provide you with an result in an arraylist like object so you would query the rest of information you like by just providing the attribute name,  you would find a list of LDAP attributes here

[LDAP attributes](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/LDAP_attributes_active_directory.htm)

Comment: thanks mohammad for your reply.. but still the error is same.. dont hv any clue to get rid of it.. it shows the error as - `Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.InvalidNameException: cn=DOMAIN\Win: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, comment: Error processing name, data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'cn=DOMAIN\Win'`

Comment: domain name is - `HDOMAIN.local`

Comment: okay i'll tell about my setup, i am on a corporate network and the domain name is dalgroup.com,,, so i went to the system properties of my pc and set it as a member of the domain, then this was the directory entry object that i made
 DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DALGROUP", domainAccountName@dalgroup.com, password);
then i made a directory searcher object to use this entry and gave it the filter criteria

Comment: Ok.. thanks for the reply. I have to figure out equivalent of DirectoryEntry in java.. I guess `HDOMAIN.local` - is it due to `.local` instead of that it should be `.com`.. does that make sense?

Comment: am not sure, i guess it's just the domain name that is configured.